# "Failed Running" error message after typing in NPM run start to use Mocha for Testspecs

Tags: error-handling, connection

I've been working on coding assignment about express routers, and using Mocha for my test specs. Most of my test specs from previous models have been working, but When i went to express router module, this error showed up.
I received an error that doesn't have an error code with it, and I have no idea what could possibly be the error. Mocha also stopped refreshing and checking my testspecs solely on my router.js after I save my files.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySs1K.png)
[package JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go1br.png)

Thank you in advance!! I appreciate it!

I have tried reinstalling NPM, thinking it was a misinstalled NPM package.
I rechecked all my module.exports on my files, I've checked database connection, but I haven't done anything with databases yet besides making the database name.
I've checked all my require() statement to make sure my paths are right.